# js dtree Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, styles

when i use dtree to make a treeform ,the following is my code:

```
<div id="combdtree" class="dtreecob">         
                     <div class="dtree" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">

                        $.ajax({
                            url : "${ctxPath}/type/list",
                            dataType : 'text',
                            type : 'get',
                            async : false,
                            success : function(data) {
                                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                                   
                                    tree.add(obj[i].id, obj[i].pid, obj[i].name, 
//                                          "javascript:setSrcValue(/''+ obj[i].name + '/',/''+ obj[i].pid+ '/')"
                                            ); 
                                }
                                document.write(tree);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    loadData();
                    </script>
                    <div class="dBottom"><a href="javascript:hiddenDTree();" mce_href="javascript:hiddenDTree();">关闭</a></div>
var srcElement = null;
        var valueElement = null;
       function showTree(item,valueId){
        srcElement = window.event.srcElement;
        valueElement = document.getElementById(valueId);
        var x = getLeft(item);
        var y = getTop(item) + item.offsetHeight;
        var w = item.offsetWidth;
        blockDTree(x,y,w);
        }
        function getTop(e){ 
        var offset=e.offsetTop;
        if(e.offsetParent!=null) offset+=getTop(e.offsetParent); 
        return offset; 
        } 
        function getLeft(e){ 
        var offset=e.offsetLeft; 
        if(e.offsetParent!=null) offset+=getLeft(e.offsetParent); 
        return offset; 
        } 
        function blockDTree(x,y,w){
            var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");
            item.style.display = 'block';
            item.style.top = y;
            item.style.left = x;
        }
        function hiddenDTree(){
            var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");
            if(item){
                item.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function setSrcValue(text,value){
            srcElement.value = text;
            valueElement.value = value;
            hiddenDTree();
        }
```

the follow is my error:

```
Home:731 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
2VM11474:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: addNodes is not defined
```

i find some same errors,but i do not find a good ways to solve it .how to correct it? Js is new for me . the second error maybe about window.addNode,but i don't know how to use it?

Comment: use the condition `if(item)` where you access `style` property of `item`

Comment: where is "combdtree" ?